# Store csv files on Azure blobs

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have few csv file present on my local system. I want to upload them into Azure blobs in a particular directory structure. I need to create the directory structure as well on azure.
Please suggest the possible options to achieve that.

Comment: Could you please show or tell us what you did so far? What language are you using?

Comment: Here's a quick tutorial which you can done the upload using in Portal https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-portal and for .Net you can try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet?tabs=windows

Answer (score 0):

1 - Create Your storage in Azure

2 - get Azure storage explorer

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/

3- start the app, login and Navigate to your Blob

4- Drag and drop folder and files :)

basically this MS provided Software allows you to use your storage account in a classic folders and files structure